# Backup failed due to insufficient storage in the iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

I just bought 20GB iCloud storage. But still, I couldn't back up my phone. Why?

Answer (score 1):

20 GB might still not be enough. Go to Settings → iCloud → Backup and check the Next Backup size to make sure it is less than the free space on your iCloud account.